# Customize publication report output names

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Is there a way to customize the names or use placeholders for the Business Objects publication report outputs when the destination is Default Enterprise location? We can use placeholders for the email destination but I can't find a similar function for Default Enterprise location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use *Default Enterprise Location* as destination, the resulting document (DeskI, WebI, publication, …) will appear as an instance in the history of the object you scheduled (right-click the object in the CMC or InfoView/Launchpad and select *History* to view the instances).

While you cannot use placeholders to rename the instance name, you can change the instance name (which defaults to the parent document's name) while scheduling. To do so, go to *Instance Title* in the sidebar navigation while scheduling and change it to whatever you'd like.

[image]